# Drop Down Text Display using Android Action Bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Can anyone point me to an example of displaying text in a view that "unrolls" down from the Android Action bar when the corresponding item is touched?

In my case, I want to display GPS state information such number of visible satellites, but that's not really important, it's just text data.  The distinction, in this case, is that I don't want to display a drop-down menu, just text data -- that changes over time, but has no function.

I'll keep searching, but at this point, I'm not even sure what to use for a search phrase.

Thanks,
R.

I got some assistance at one point with how to add a spinner to my ActionBar.  The spinner display DOES allow me to temporarily drop below the "normal" Action Bar space, but I don't know how to fix its label at the top.  Does this make any sense?  If could use a spinner without losing the Action Bar label, it would probably be perfect.  Does anybody know how I might do that?  Does anybody think I probably should have opened a separate case??

Thanks, R.

Comment: Did you look at ActionBar.setActionView()?  This can be used to pass on a custom navigation style for the action bar.

Comment: I didn't know it existed, but I'm digging for information on it now.  If you know of an example somewhere, that would really be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
View customeView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_action_bar_layout, null);
getActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true)
getActionBar().setCustomView(addView);
```

Also refer: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-developers/mDUJ1yYcVPQ/ATwHNLg1OA0J

Comment: Well, those are some pretty thin samples, but I'll see what I can make of them.  Do you know if adding a custom view completely replaces the default view or adds to it??

Comment: Interestingly, it would appear that although I can add a text view to my ActionBar (adds to the default view, doesn't replace it) and control the text in it, I can't go outside the established border of of the Action Bar to do it.  Sadly, that's precisely what I'm trying to do.  I'll keep digging.

Comment: I guess that'd be expected, that whatever view you add to the actionbar can be contained only within the AB. BTW, what default view you mentioned, is it like having icon and title?

Comment: In my application, I'm hiding the title but displaying the icon.  Other than that, I'm just displaying the ActionBar the Android OS is giving me, with my menu items to the right.  I know you can make one or more menu items a spinner, and the spinner will extend below the ActionBar's normal space.  At this point, my plan is to try to finagle something using that function, but I don't have anything that would be an answer to this post, yet.